Does the input DC power of a power amplifier stay constant during operation?
So the power amplifier takes the AC input signal and amplifies it, so we get the AC output signal with a larger power than that of the input signal. And the energy required to amplify the signal comes from the input DC power. I'm wondering if the input DC power stays constant during the amplification. I'm assuming input the DC power is the voltage bias multiplied by the current bias. For example, class A amplifier with maximum drain current of 1 A and breakdown voltage of 10 V, we would bias the transistor at 0.5 A and 5 V, therefore the DC source supplies 2.5 W during the power amplification. Am I correct on this or am I misunderstanding how the power amplifiers work?
I started wondering about this when I thought about class B operation where the current bias is zero. With my understanding, this would mean that the DC source is not supplying any power to the amplifier. Where am I wrong in my understanding?

You are correct for the class-A amplifier. The output stage will always be conducting and burning power in the quiescent state. This is because the output transistor is always biased to its linear (ohmic) regime. There are no discontinuities on the voltage swing. So when it's designed properly, you have perfect linearity (and no crossover distortion) with respect to the input signal.
For pure class B amplifiers, the only current drawn from the supply at no input signal is the quiescent current to bias the previous "pre-amp stage(s)" that are usually class-A amplifiers. If you are only considering the output "totem poll" or "push-pull" power stage, neglecting the rest of the circuitry, then you are correct, the output stage consumes no power with no input signal. In fact, it consumes no power even for a few hundred mV input amplitude into this stage because the transistors need almost a diode drop in either direction to get the transistors to draw current off the DC power rails.
Which is why class-AB is used in practice for "linear" audio amplifies - it bias the output transistors into mild cross-conduction so that collectively, at any point in the signal slew, either one or both transistors are conducting. This eliminates crossover distortion and drastically improves linearity and reduces THD for a small penalty in efficiency.

I see, thank you so much. I have an additional question: In the case of the class AB amplifier (let's say again the transistor has maximum drain current of 1 A and breakdown voltage of 10 V), we would bias it at (Vdsq,Idsq) = (5V, ~0.1 A), which means P_DC is only 0.5 W. But the output power will be 1/8VppIpp = 1.25 W, which is more than what the DC source supplies. In this case how is the power conserved? Sorry for the naive question..

@user207787 It's not. That's the fundamental point. In class-B and AB designs the power goes up with increasing signal amplitude. The relationship would be more like:: quiescent current + bias current + and (variable) amplification current = power supply draw.  TBH, I'm not really following your reasoning: we have to at least assume the DC source has enough juice to power the circuit or else all analysis goes out the window.

@user207787 Also, I don't know why the transistor has an assumed breakdown of 10V? This sounds like a bad assumption or bad choice of transistor for the design. The absolute voltage the transistor is irrelevant from a biasing standpoint. It just needs to barley conduct in AB operation - a small fraction of what the amplifier is expected to produce.
